# unable to align components properly

Tags: vaadin7

I want to align my components in the window like this

[image]

The problem is that no matter how I try using layouts and setting widths and heights - it's either on the top of the window(almost in the border) or too far from the center.

Currently it looks like this

[image]

My code for the window looks like this

```
public MakeChoiceWindow(TextPage page) {
    setHeight("300");
    setWidth("550");

    VerticalLayout windowLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    windowLayout.setSizeFull();


    VerticalLayout wrapped = new VerticalLayout();
    wrapped.setWidth("520");
    wrapped.setHeight("250");

    HorizontalLayout textAndChoiceLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    textAndChoiceLayout.setWidth("400");

    wrapped.addComponent(new Label(" "));

    choiceMessageArea = new TextArea();
    choiceMessageArea.setValue(page.getTextMessage());
    choiceMessageArea.setWidth("250");
    choiceMessageArea.setHeight("150");
    textAndChoiceLayout.addComponent(choiceMessageArea);
    textAndChoiceLayout.setComponentAlignment(choiceMessageArea, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);

    choiceRadioGroup = new OptionGroup("Your choice");
    for(int i = 0; i < page.numberOfChoices(); i++) {
        choiceRadioGroup.addItem(page.getChoice(i));
    }
    choiceRadioGroup.select(page.getChoice(0));
    choiceRadioGroup.setHeight("100");
    textAndChoiceLayout.addComponent(choiceRadioGroup);
    textAndChoiceLayout.setComponentAlignment(choiceRadioGroup, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);

    wrapped.addComponent(textAndChoiceLayout);
    wrapped.setComponentAlignment(textAndChoiceLayout, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

    makeChoiceButton = new Button();
    makeChoiceButton.setWidth("100");
    makeChoiceButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.CHECK);
    makeChoiceButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            MakeChoiceWindow.this.close();
        }

    });

    wrapped.addComponent(makeChoiceButton);
    wrapped.setComponentAlignment(makeChoiceButton, Alignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

    windowLayout.addComponent(wrapped);
    windowLayout.setComponentAlignment(wrapped, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);

    setContent(windowLayout);
    center();
    setModal(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

What should I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to align components somehow.

Thus not perfect (maybe I should play with components` sizes)

```
public MakeChoiceWindow(TextPage page) {
    setCaption("Suddenly!");
    setHeight("300");
    setWidth("550");

    VerticalLayout windowLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    windowLayout.setWidth("500");
    windowLayout.setHeight("230");

    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.setWidth("480");
    horizontalLayout.setHeight("200");

    TextArea textMessageArea = new TextArea();
    textMessageArea.setValue(page.getTextMessage());
    textMessageArea.setWidth("360");
    textMessageArea.setHeight("180");
    textMessageArea.setEnabled(false);

    horizontalLayout.addComponent(textMessageArea);
    horizontalLayout.setComponentAlignment(textMessageArea, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);

    OptionGroup choiceRadioGroup = new OptionGroup("Your choice");
    for(int i = 0; i < page.numberOfChoices(); i++) {
        choiceRadioGroup.addItem(page.getChoice(i));
    }
    choiceRadioGroup.select(page.getChoice(0));
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(choiceRadioGroup);
    horizontalLayout.setComponentAlignment(choiceRadioGroup, Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT);

    windowLayout.addComponent(horizontalLayout);
    windowLayout.setComponentAlignment(horizontalLayout, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);

    Button makeChoiceButton = new Button();
    makeChoiceButton.setWidth("100");
    makeChoiceButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.CHECK);
    makeChoiceButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            MakeChoiceWindow.this.close();
        }

    });
    windowLayout.addComponent(makeChoiceButton);
    windowLayout.setComponentAlignment(makeChoiceButton, Alignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

    setContent(windowLayout);
    center();
    setModal(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

Now it looks like this

[image]